# Why $(M/M \operatorname{rad} A) \operatorname{rad}A=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ a right $A$-module. Why we have $(M/M \operatorname{rad}A) \operatorname{rad}A=0$? Thank you very much.

Comment: COuld you explain your notation a bit more? From my point of view it looks like you have an ideal $I$ of $A$ and you're asking why $(M/IM)I=0$, which should follow pretty quick from the fact that $IM/IM=0$?

Comment: @Alex, thank you very much. But when I take $m\in M, a\in I$, then $(m+MI)a=ma+MI=MI \neq 0$. Do we think $MI$ as 0 of $M/mI$?

Comment: @Jianrong $MI$ *is* the zero element of $M/MI$ - try adding it to anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You can replace $\mathrm{rad}(A)$ with any right ideal of $A$.